# Pybind 11: How to bind C++ function that has pointer arguments?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Let's suppose I am given a function that looks like this

```
void myFunc(int *a){
  a[0]++;
  a[1]++;
}
```

I tried to bind this function with the below

```
#include "pybind11/numpy.h"
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(pybindtest, m) {
  m.def("myFunc", [](py::array_t<int> buffer){
    py::buffer_info info = buffer.request();
    myFunc(static_cast<int *>(info.ptr));
  });
}
```

and use the below python code to test

```
import pybindtest

a=[1,2];

pybindtest.myFunc(a);

print(a)
```

This shows `[1, 2]` instead of `[2, 3]`. Given that `myFunc` is written by other people, so I am not allowed to change the API. Is it possible to bind this function into python? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Python integers are very different from C++'s `int`s, so this really shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your python script

```py
import numpy as np
import pybindtest

a=np.array([1,2], dtype=np.int32);

pybindtest.myFunc(a);

print(a)
```

The problem is that `a` is a python list, not an array of ints. By default pybind11 will convert the list into a suitable array - see the section about `py::array::forcecast` in the [docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html?highlight=numpy#arrays). But in doing so it creates a copy and the increments in `myFunc` are performed on that.

Comment: It works! But it's `pybindtest.myFunc(a);` instead of `pybindtest(a);`

Comment: Oops thanks. Edited.